# HTTP status code to return by a REST API when image size exceeds limit

Tags: api, rest, http-status-codes, http-status-code-400

A POST to a specific end point allows to upload an image except if the image is too large, so I want to return the appropiate http status code response in that case.

A http status code 400 response it does not seem to fit well in this case.

> 400 Bad Request: "The server cannot or will not process the request due
>   to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

I think that the image being too large it does not imply that the request  is malformed or syntactically incorrect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use 420 or even 422, but I would avoid that until you have really good reason to have separate code for it. Usually is better to keep number of different status codes rather small. Check top 10 on that list: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

You should avoid using more than 10 codes, because your API will become too complex.

So my answer is: use **400** with proper error message returned to the client like: **"Image too large, you can upload files up to XX MB"**

Answer (score 19):

This seems like it would be an ideal candidate for 413 Payload Too Large. From [Section 6.5.11 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.11):

> The 413 (Payload Too Large) status code indicates that the server is
> refusing to process a request because the request payload is larger
> than the server is willing or able to process.